# Conflict on template of Tornado and Vue

Tags: vuejs2, tornado

I'm a newbie to both these frameworks and the first thing I found is a conflict. So because the double curly brackets are reserved by Tornado, I changed the Vue's default ones to single ones:

```
      new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
```

Template:

```
<td>${ message }</td>
```

But now it's just not rendered, what I see in a browser is:

```
${ message }
```

How to solve this conflict? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

UPD I figured it out. I did several things wrong:
1) I put the script at the "head" section instead of the very end.
2) I didn't add id="app" attribute to some parent element to specify the app object.
After I changed the code everything started working.

Comment: If you don't really need Tornado's server side rendering feature, you can just serve the template without rendering and do your stuff in Vue.

Comment: @xyres, I need both - client and server side rendering. I can't believe that nobody encountered this problem :(

Answer (score 5):

Another way to combine Tornado with another template system that uses double-braces is to escape the ones that are to be handled by javascript with `{{!`:

```
<h1>This variable comes from Tornado: {{ x }}</h1>
<p>This one comes from Vue: {{! y }}</p>
```

Tornado's rendering will remove the exclamation point and leave the double braces for Vue to use.

Comment: While this works, IDE (e.g. JetBrains PyCharm) will indicate the error "Id or literal expected". Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that as well. This is what worked for me.

Put this in your main.js. N.B you can specify the delimiters to suit your needs

```
Vue.mixin({ delimiters: ['[[',']]'] })
```

The in your html you can use it as it is. e.g

```
<td>[[ message ]]</td>
```